# Is load balancer unnecessary for k3s embeded etcd HA solution

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability, rancher, k3s

I have a same [discussion](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/discussions/4488) in k3s github repository, but no one reply. Hope someone can give an answer here.

There are articles talking about the embedded etcd HA solution of k3s like [this](https://blog.alexellis.io/bare-metal-kubernetes-with-k3s/). One of the key behavior is adding a load balancer solution (EIP like this article or LB from the clound provider) between the agents and masters:

```
k3s agent --> load balancer --> master
```

And the [architecture of k3s](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/architecture/#fixed-registration-address-for-agent-nodes) also show that a **Fixed Registration Address** is necessary.

While, after some research I found that k3s (at least v1.21.5+k3s2) have a internal agent load balancer (config at `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/k3s-agent-load-balancer.yaml`) which will auto update the master k8s api server list in it. So the out side load balancer is unnecessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a response from the k3s discussion:

https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/discussions/4488#discussioncomment-1719009

> Our documentation lists a requirement for a "fixed registration endpoint" so that nodes do not rely on a single server being online in order to join the cluster. This endpoint could be a load-balancer or a DNS alias, it's up to you. This is only needed when nodes are registering to the cluster; once they have successfully joined, they use the client load-balancer to communicate directly with the servers without going through the registration endpoint.

I think this is good enough to answer this question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, an external load balancer is still required to achieve a highly available setup with more than one master node.

Whenever you start a worker node or use the API, you should connect to the external load balancer to ensure you can connect to a running master node if one master is currently down.

The internal load balancer you mentioned above distributes any load within your cluster.

Comment: Could you please tell more detail about the agent load balancer?